# How can i solve this excel macro bug

Tags: excel, vba

i can't find where i am doing wrong my code is not working so. I'm a bit of a novice at this, I don't quite understand what the problem is

it gives me warning on this line
matrix = Range("B5").Resize(rows, cols)

```
Sub TamsayiliRasgeleMatris()

'Deklarasyonlar
Dim rows As Integer, cols As Integer
Dim lowerBound As Integer, upperBound As Integer
Dim sum As Double, average As Double

'Kullanıcıdan girdiler alma
rows = Range("A2").Value
cols = Range("B2").Value
lowerBound = Range("C2").Value
upperBound = Range("D2").Value

'Boş bir matris oluşturma
Dim matrix As Variant
matrix = Range("B5").Resize(rows, cols)

'Matrisi rastgele sayılarla doldurma
For i = 1 To rows
For j = 1 To cols
matrix(i, j) = Int((upperBound - lowerBound + 1) * Rnd + lowerBound)
sum = sum + matrix(i, j)
Next j
Next i

'Matrisi çalışma sayfasına yazma
matrix.Copy Destination:=Range("B5")

'Ortalama değerini hesaplayın ve E2 hücresine yazma
average = sum / (rows * cols)
Range("E2").Value = average

'Matris transpozunu oluşturun ve altına yapıştırın
Dim transposed As Variant
transposed = Application.Transpose(matrix)
transposed.Copy Destination:=Range("B5").Offset(rows + 1, 0)

'Değerleri ortalama değerine göre renklendirin
For i = 1 To rows
For j = 1 To cols
If matrix(i, j) < average Then
matrix(i, j).Interior.Color = vbCyan
ElseIf matrix(i, j) > average Then
matrix(i, j).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
End If
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried but it still says error here

Comment: you should also check actual values of rows and cols variables when you reach that line

Answer (score 2):

### Understanding Ranges and Arrays

[image]
[image]

- A lot was changed so some of your comments may not apply anymore.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TamsayiliRasgeleMatris()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Improve!
    
    'Kullanicidan girdiler alma
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = ws.Range("A2").Value
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = ws.Range("B2").Value
    Dim MinInteger As Long: MinInteger = ws.Range("C2").Value
    Dim MaxInteger As Long: MaxInteger = ws.Range("D2").Value
    
    'Boş bir matris oluşturma
    Dim Matrix() As Variant: ReDim Matrix(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, Total As Long
    
    'Matrisi rastgele sayilarla doldurma
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Matrix(r, c) = Int((MaxInteger - MinInteger + 1) * Rnd + MinInteger)
            Total = Total + Matrix(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    ws.Range("E2").Value = Total
    
    Dim rg As Range, fCell As Range
    
    'Matrisi çalişma sayfasina yazma
    Set fCell = ws.Range("B5")
    
    With fCell
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, ws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1).Clear
    End With
    
    Set rg = fCell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    rg.Value = Matrix
    
    'Ortalama degerini hesaplayin ve F2 hücresine yazma
    Dim Avg As Double: Avg = Total / (rCount * cCount)
    ws.Range("F2").Value = Avg
    
    'Degerleri ortalama degerine göre renklendirin
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Select Case Matrix(r, c)
                Case Is < Avg: rg.Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                Case Is > Avg: rg.Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                Case Else ' !?
            End Select
        Next c
    Next r
    
    'Matris transpozunu oluşturun ve altina yapiştirin
    Dim tMatrix() As Long: ReDim tMatrix(1 To cCount, 1 To rCount)
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            tMatrix(c, r) = Matrix(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    
    Set fCell = fCell.Offset(rCount + 1)
    Set rg = fCell.Resize(cCount, rCount)
    
    rg.Value = tMatrix
    
    'Degerleri ortalama degerine göre renklendirin
    For c = 1 To cCount
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Select Case tMatrix(c, r)
                Case Is < Avg: rg.Cells(c, r).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                Case Is > Avg: rg.Cells(c, r).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
                Case Else ' !?
            End Select
        Next r
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here follow some suggestion to possibly make your code run

taking in consideration the following code snippet:

```
Dim matrix As Variant
matrix = Range("B5").Resize(rows, cols)
```

since:

- `matrix` is declared as of `Variant` type
- `Value` is the default property for any `Range` object

then `matrix` is finally resulting in a `Variant` array, as if you had coded:

```
    matrix = Range("B5").Resize(rows, cols).Value
```

further on you are coding:

```
matrix.Copy Destination:=Range("B5")
```

which would result in an error since an array doesn't have any `Copy` method, while this latter is available for many objects, among which the `Range` object

hence you should sort of "reverse" the matrix assignation code line as follows:

```
'Matrisi çalisma sayfasina yazma
Range("B5").Resize(rows, cols).Value = matrix
```

just a little more complicated is the fix of the other wrong `Copy` statement

```
Dim transposed As Variant
transposed = Application.Transpose(matrix)
transposed.Copy Destination:=Range("B5").Offset(rows + 1, 0)
```

which, along the lines of the preceeding fix, is to be coded as follows:

```
Dim transposed As Variant
    transposed = Application.Transpose(matrix)
    Range("B5").Offset(rows + 1, 0).Resize(cols, rows).Value = transposed
```

and where you'll notice I swapped `cols` and `rows` in the `Resize()` property to account for transposition

finally the following snippet:

```
'Değerleri ortalama değerine göre renklendirin
For i = 1 To rows
For j = 1 To cols
If matrix(i, j) < average Then
matrix(i, j).Interior.Color = vbCyan
ElseIf matrix(i, j) > average Then
matrix(i, j).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
End If
Next j
Next i
```

is to be twicked as follows:

```
With Range("B5") 'reference the target range upper-left cell
    For i = 1 To rows
        For j = 1 To cols
            If matrix(i, j) < average Then
                .Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Interior.Color = vbCyan 'write in the cell corresponding to the ith row and jth column of matrix
            ElseIf matrix(i, j) > average Then
                .Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Interior.Color = vbMagenta
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
```